# Forcing the Qt GUI to update

Tags: c++, multithreading, debugging, qt, thread-safety

I am coding a boardgame in Qt where, after the player makes a move, the computer AI must pause and think for some time. However, while it is thinking, it seems the screen will not be updated until every line of code has been executed. Thus, the user would click on a square, see nothing happen for a few seconds, and then suddenly see the result of both his move *and* the computer's move.

In an attempt to fix this, I tried creating a new thread on which the AI runs its code, and then places its piece on the board. However, sometimes (and this is very inconsistent) the game crashes after the computer has made a move.

So can you guys either:

1. Tell me how force the MainWindow to update its contents
2. Help me try to debug the crashing problem (I'm totally new to threads)

**EDIT**--I tried setting breakpoints as suszterpatt suggested, and the program seems to crash consistently in the debugger (it wasn't before I set the breakpoints).

Anyways, as I step through the program, it seems to go through the `run` function fine, until it reaches the ending bracket, and then if I step through it jumps into line 317 on `qthread_win.cpp`, which just says

```
finish(arg); //line 317
return 0;
```

If I step through that line, the debugger freezes up and Qt alerts me after 20 seconds. If I continue, I get the "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way" message that I get when the program occasionally crashes when I'm not debugging.

What should I do now?

Comment: You should stick with creating a separate AI thread. Debugging shouldn't be *too* hard with only 2 threads, especially if you already know where the crashes occur: you can probably just plop down some breakpoints and see which one's the last to get executed, then narrow it down from there.

Comment: @susz okay sure, but I'm not too sure where the crashes occur though. Going to google setting breakpoints in qt...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cause of the crash can be a variety of reasons but if I had to take a guess I'd say you're probably calling methods of a GUI object (label, textbox, your game board, etc.) from the AI thread.

The way threads communicate with one another in Qt is through a mechanism called [signals and slots](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/signalsandslots.html): the AI thread should expose a set of signals, i.e. 'beginThink', 'endThink', and the UI thread should register to those signals (with slots) and react accordingly. This is documented pretty throughly in the docs.

Comment: Ah, so should I ditch the function pointers I am currently using and switch to using signals and slots instead?

Comment: @wrong: Absolutely. Qt does few things right IMO, but signals and slots are definitely one of them.

Comment: While I don't have anything in the AI thread that calls any GUI stuff, I am seeing `QPainter::begin: A paint device can only be painted by one painter at a time.
QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active` and `QPainter::drawRects: Painter not active` repeatedly before it crashes.

Comment: Thank you so much! fiddled around with signals and slots a bit and finally got it working. btw the problem was here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446731/when-does-a-thread-exit

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your code out of the separate thread. Once you have it working you can try moving it back and you will know any issues are threading related. I think your updating issue will go away if it's all on the same thread.

Comment: The code works fine if I call the `run` method directly instead of starting the thread with `start`. I'm pretty sure it's threading related, but what do you want to be "all on the same thread"?