# When does a thread exit?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, thread-safety

I have code in Qt that goes like this:

```
void doSomeStuff()
{
    ...
    if(blah blah)
        someObj.start();
    ...
}
```

and then `someObj.run()`:

```
void someObj::run()
{
    blah blah blah, do some stuff
    doSomeStuff()
}
```

What I was **intending** is for the new thread created at `someObj.start()` to end and then the function `doSomeStuff` in the main thread gets called again once it stops. But my program was crashing randomly, and when I closely followed the code again, I realized that perhaps the real case was that the new thread merely calls the function without dying off, thus spawning new threads continuously. Are my suspicions correct? If so, how should I remedy this?

Comment: Why would calling a function in a thread cause that function to be run anywhere other than the thread that calls it? Also, -1 for not trying it first.

Comment: @Falmarri exactly, so I wanted to check here if my intuition was correct. Btw, what should I have tried first?

Comment: @Falmarri maybe you thought I had written some code and hadn't tried it yet and posted here... I should update the question to make that clearer

Comment: Running it. Also, exactly what? I'm saying you're wrong. doSomeStuff() gets called inside the thread. It ends when it exits its run() method.

Comment: @wrongusername: Well if you didn't write some code first, you should have. This shouldn't be the first place you come for every question. Come here when you get stuck.

Comment: @Falmarri I'm sorry, something's wrong with my mind and I'm unable to understand what you're saying right now :( What you say seems to be exactly what I'm thinking, so I don't really get where I'm wrong. New threads are being created all the time because the two functions keep calling each other. Is that logic wrong?

Comment: @Falmarri I did write some code first, okay? That was just a simplified version of the code I had written, which didn't really work (like I said it kept crashing). And I've been debugging this for a couple hours now, I'm truly stuck and I don't want to keep guessing wrong so I came here to ask if the code I have is indeed a problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

doSomeStuff() is currently called when the thread is exectured ego the thread will still be alive otherwise it would not be called at all ^^ only when doSomeStuff is finished then your Thread will exit

By glancing at the QT doc (I'm no Qt expert) I found

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html

> bool  isFinished () const

you could said a callback from there

Comment: How would I implement a callback?

Answer (score 1):

this seems a bit confusing.  You say that your main thread calls `doSomeStuff()` to launch a thread every now and then, but you also call it in the thread run function.  I'm just going to assume there's two cases.  I think the most probable case is that you want the thread to run exactly once for each time the doSomeStuff is called in the main thread, If so:

```
void doSomeStuff()
{
    ...
    if(blah blah)
    {
        if(someObj.isRunning())
            someObj.wait();
        someObj.start();
    }
    ...
}

void someObj::run()
{
    blah blah blah, do some stuff
}
```

If you actually do want the thread body to loop over and over, just use a `while` loop instead of trying to call it again.  You probably, in this case, intend for the thread to definitely be running for *sure* each time doSomeStuff gets called, so you need to be a bit more clever:

```
bool someObjRun = false;
QMutex someObjRunLock;

void doSomeStuff()
{
    ...
    if(blah blah)
    {
        someObjRunLock.lock();
        someObjRun = true;

        if (!someObj.isRunning() )
            someObj.start();

        someObjRunLock.unlock();
    }
    ...
}

void someObj::run()
{
    someObjRunLock.lock()
    while( someObjRun )
    {
        someObjRunLock.unlock();

        blah blah blah, do some stuff

        someObjRunLock.lock()
        if(should quit...)
        {
            someObjRun = false;
        }

    }
    someObjRunLock.unlock()
}
```

Comment: I think it's the first case. I want the main loop to call the thread, have the thread execute its statements and then die, and then have the `doSomeStuff` function run again. So would `someObj.wait` wait until the other thread has stopped running?

Comment: yes, `QThread.wait()` blocks the calling thread until the target thread exits.  (http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qthread.html#wait)