# how to change GUI while processing

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am new to Qt Programming, but I have basic on C++.

I want to update my GUI while it is processing, example:

```
while (....)
{

        do some calculation...

        if (condition fulfill)

            change the color of label.
}
```

However, I realise that I failed to get the result I want (update the GUI while processing). The GUI will only update after the while loop.
Why is it so? Anyone can help?

In addition, I wish to "slower" the color change since the processing is too fast and I can't see the animation. Any idea to do it?

Thank you very much!

**Clarification:**
Actually I wish to update the GUI *while* I am processing...Meaning that, if I have 100 iteration, after **each** iteration I wish to update the GUI *immediately*.

Comment: You might find a library I wrote, Thinker-Qt, interesting to look at (it's really in an alpha state though): http://hostilefork.com/thinker-qt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place your processing code to another thread and update the gui, because like this GUI will be waiting for your process to end and will refresh after its end

read more here:
http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/41545-How-to-refresh-GUI-while-heavy-processing-is-ongoing
http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/32416-Update-GUI-from-another-thread
[Forcing the Qt GUI to update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443988/forcing-the-qt-gui-to-update)

Comment: Meaning that, I should do like this??
while(...)
{
        do some calculation...
        if (condition fulfill)
            create a new thread to update GUI
}

Comment: actually a timer is a simpler way to do this. Threading not needed.

Comment: and if you are going to use threading, and you shouldn't, you only need one thread, not one per loop.

Comment: My processing is too fast and it makes my GUI no responsive (since too many signals are sent in a very short time to update GUI). I need to "sleep" the processing thread to keep my GUI update....

Answer (score 2):

Use a QTimer. This will allow you to control the speed of your animation and keep your UI responsive.

Comment: Can QTimer update the GUI after each iteration as mentioned above? I failed to do it as the GUI will only update after the whole iterations...

Comment: Timers are very commonly used to update gui at regular intervals

Comment: what do you mean by slow? I don't believe you understand timers.

Comment: Ops sorry, I meant I still need to do multithreading because although I used the QTimer to update the GUI immediately (I put 0 milisec), the GUI will only redraw after the whole iteration is finished...

Comment: @spflee These comments indicate that you are not fully familiar with how message loops work. I recommend reading up on message loops and event driven architectures. That said, you are probably right that the long running task should be on a thread. However, if you want regular, updates to the UI then a timer can be used in conjunction. A timer will allow you to specify an update frequency that will be obeyed no matter how fast or slow the worker thread executes.

Comment: Yea, thank you very much for your comment. It is my fault actually. I found the reason why the GUI didn't update if I use QTimer. There are too many signals sent in a very short time to update GUI (since few hundred iterations could be finished in hundreds milisec). That's why the GUI didn't update accordingly and it hangs. QTimer works nicely actually. Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need a thread.
Calling [QApplication::processEvents()](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.7/qcoreapplication.html#id-935de322-b16a-4704-90d3-506b939fc016%20QApplication%3a%3aprocessEvents%28%29) will process pending events, including any redraws you may have caused during your processing.

Comment: you would still have to sleep the gui thread which is never good

Comment: That's assuming you want to do your processing in another thread, which is not always needed. And the original post sounds like he's not multithreading.

Comment: no, I'm assuming all processing in main gui thread. Current code would need sleeps to slow transitions down. Timer is the canonical solution.

Comment: Ah that; change color every 100 iterations or something like that.

Comment: and what about different processor speeds? Timer is hands down the best solution in a message driven setting.

Comment: We could go on forever with this :) Assume you put the color change on a timer, then the processing loop locks up... the color changes will not be an indication that something is going on in the background any more. Still, the site is warning me that we should move to chat, so let's end this.

Comment: Thanks, this actually work if I use single thread, but of course the GUI will not responsive...

Comment: GUI won't be responsive single threaded unless you run the GUI event loop all the time (once per work loop iteration). From the question it didn't look like you want the GUI to work, just the status label to redraw. For the generic "how do I do background processing in a GUI app" question, both the main thread and separate thread answers are correct, with different trade offs :)

Comment: Yup, exactly, this works well for my situation...I had tried both methods (single thread with QApplication::processEvents() and multithread) and both also works nicely :)..Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to animate the color to indicate that the system is currently working, you might want to use QApplication::setOverrideCursor to show a waitCursor, or a QProgressDialog instead.